# Query string vs SQL Filter statement

Tags: rest, query-string

I am developing a rest-api. 
My api maps a query string like: `email=xyz@gmail.com&gender=MALE` in a sql statement: `where email = xyz@gmail.com.br and gender = MALE`

So why not pass the SQL statament using just a POST method instead of a GET?

Is there any best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Because that would not be REST, it would be something like SOAP.

REST is about resources and operations on them. If you implement REST using HTTP, there are HTTP verbs that should be used for specifict actions:

- `GET` is for getting a resource
- `POST` is for creating a new resource in a collection (plus some special cases
- `PUT` is for changing an existing resource
- `DELETE` is for deleting an existing resource

These verbs must follow a specific behaviour. One of these is that `GET` must not change the resource while `POST` usually does change it.

Using `POST` instead of `GET` is against REST and all established standards.

> why not pass the SQL statament using just a POST

Because this would expose details about your implementation to the user. This can open security holes. REST is about resources, an abstraction, not about the easies way to expose a database.